# Can't Create regex for specific list in json

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need only first part (highlighted in green on attachment), and I want it to highlight date that goes after word 'data'. It is important to use it in expression.
End the second part, that goes after "not" shouldn't match
I need it for performance script generation
data:

```
{"data":["2023-05-31T00:00:00Z","2023-04-30T00:00:00Z","2023-03-31T00:00:00Z","2023-02-28T00:00:00Z","2023-01-31T00:00:00Z","2022-12-31T00:00:00Z","2022-11-30T00:00:00Z","2022-10-31T00:00:00Z","2022-09-30T00:00:00Z","2022-08-31T00:00:00Z","2022-07-31T00:00:00Z","2022-06-30T00:00:00Z","2022-05-31T00:00:00Z","2022-04-30T00:00:00Z","2022-03-31T00:00:00Z","2022-02-28T00:00:00Z","2022-01-31T00:00:00Z","2021-12-31T00:00:00Z","2021-11-30T00:00:00Z","2021-10-31T00:00:00Z","2021-09-30T00:00:00Z","2021-08-31T00:00:00Z","2021-07-31T00:00:00Z","2021-06-30T00:00:00Z","2021-05-31T00:00:00Z","2021-04-30T00:00:00Z","2021-03-31T00:00:00Z","2021-02-28T00:00:00Z","2021-01-31T00:00:00Z","2020-12-31T00:00:00Z","2020-11-30T00:00:00Z","2020-10-31T00:00:00Z"], {"not":["2023-05-31T00:00:00Z","2023-04-30T00:00:00Z"], "success":true,"unicornErrorCode":null,"error":null,"errorStackTrace":null,"cache":false}
```

Curent expression: `(?>data)*([0-9\-ZT:]{5,25}Z)`

Comment: Why not `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;` and parse it properly?

Comment: As others have answered, I don't think you should use regex for json. Consider a library that handles it.

Answer (score 2):

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) so using regular expressions for parsing it is not the best idea.

Consider using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries, it will be much more robust, reliable, readable, powerful and convenient

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to capture the first date, after the *"date"* key, you can use the following.

```
data.+?(\d.+?Z)
```

```
2023-05-31T00:00:00Z
```

If you are looking to capture *all* of the dates, after the *"date"* key, use this.

```
data.+?(\".+)\]
```

Output

```
"2023-05-31T00:00:00Z", "2023-04-30T00:00:00Z", "2023-03-31T00:00:00Z", "2023-02-28T00:00:00Z", "2023-01-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-11-30T00:00:00Z", "2022-10-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-09-30T00:00:00Z", "2022-08-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-07-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-06-30T00:00:00Z", "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-04-30T00:00:00Z", "2022-03-31T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-28T00:00:00Z", "2022-01-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-11-30T00:00:00Z", "2021-10-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-09-30T00:00:00Z", "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-07-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-06-30T00:00:00Z", "2021-05-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-04-30T00:00:00Z", "2021-03-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-02-28T00:00:00Z", "2021-01-31T00:00:00Z", "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z", "2020-11-30T00:00:00Z", "2020-10-31T00:00:00Z"
```